# Janusgraph warm-up

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph, warm-up

Janusgraph does some internal activities due to which there are spikes in starting 1-2 runs.. (even at 10 QPS) and after that it gets stable. Once it's stable, no spikes are observed, is it expected behaviour, that needed some warm-up run to make it stable? Using Back-end Cassandra CQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra can exhibit behavior like this on startup.  If there are files in the commitlog (directory), those will validate and write their data to disk.  If there are a lot of them, there can be a bit of an increase in resource consumption.